# Linq2SQL get value of dynamically chosen column

Tags: entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have a POCO class describing my model:

```
public class Example
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is an extension method to project my class this way using Entity Framework DbSets:

```
var qry = db.Examples.Select(x => new {
    Prop1 = x.Prop1,
    Prop2 = x.Prop2,
    Prop3 = x.Prop3,
    Description = XXXXX
}).ToList();
```

Where XXXXX is the value of the Prop1, Prop2 or Prop3 property, wich name I now as an string only at runtime.

I cannot use Dynamic Linq, because I'm targeting Entity Framework Core, and I'm getting crazy with LINQ expressions and I think I'm still far from the solution...
Could you provide some guidance, please?

Comment: Are you always selecting a **single** property of type **string**?

Comment: No, I need a projection, or even an IQueryable<Example> if I include a dummy "Description" property in my "Example" class

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not allow projection to entity type. And anonymous types cannot be created a runtime. Take a look at Dynamic LINQ. Good luck.

Comment: I cannot use Dynamic Linq, because I'm targeting Entity Framework Core... Anyway thanks @Ivan Stoev, and sorry for my previous missunderstand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you fetch all needed properties for `Description` explicitly, you can fetch the query without `Description` and then generate the desired query from the loaded data.

Assuming the name of the property for setting `Description` is stored in `name` variable:

```
var qry1 = db.Examples.Select(x => new {
    Prop1 = x.Prop1,
    Prop2 = x.Prop2,
    Prop3 = x.Prop3,
}).ToList();
var qry = qry1.Select(x => new {
    Prop1 = x.Prop1,
    Prop2 = x.Prop2,
    Prop3 = x.Prop3,
    Description = name == "Prop1"? x.Prop1 : name == "Prop2"? x.Prop2: x.Prop3
}).ToList();
```

If you don't like hard coding the names, you can use reflection to get the value:

```
Description = GetProp(x, name)
```

where `GetProp` is:

```
private string GetProp(object y, string name)
{
   return y.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(y).ToString();
}
```

Comment: I reached the same conclusion before reading your answer. Anyway, this seems the way to go. I'll try with reflection, because this example is a simplified scenario. In the real app I have 10 properties to choose from, so making a 9 ternary operator expression seems ugly to me...